# Como tratar um Entry vazio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, validação, xamarin-forms, conversão-de-tipo

Possuo 4 entradas de texto e um botão:

---

```
<Entry x:Name="Densidade"
           Keyboard="Numeric"/>

<Entry x:Name="Volume"
           Keyboard="Numeric"/>

<Entry x:Name="Area"
           Keyboard="Numeric"/>

<Entry x:Name="Custo"
           Keyboard="Numeric"/>

<Button x:Name="Button"
            Text="Calcular"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
```

---

No code Behind eu as converto para double, faço um cálculo e envio o resultado para uma Page2 atravé da Classe2

---

```
 //Botão que transforma os dados em variáveis e passa para a página de resultados
    private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        class2 = new Class2();

        //Converte os valores obtidos na entrada em tipo double
        double a, d, r, v;
        a = Double.Parse(Area.Text);
        d = Double.Parse(Densidade.Text);
        r = Double.Parse(Custo.Text);
        v = Double.Parse(Volume.Text);

        //calculo
        class2.Calculo1 = d * a * (v / 1000) * r;

        //chama Page1 passando objeto class2
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(class2));
    }
```

---

Porém, se alguma das entradas não for preenchida, acontece o seguinte erro:
[image]

Já tentei soluções como:

---

```
private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        class2 = new Class2();

        double a, d, r, v;

        if (Densidade.Text == "")
            d = 0;
        else
            d = Double.Parse(Densidade.Text);

        if (Volume.Text == "")
            v = 0; 
        else
            v = Double.Parse(Volume.Text);

        if (Area.Text == "")
            a = 0;
        else
            a = Double.Parse(Area.Text);

        if (Custo.Text == "")
            r = 0;
        else
            r = Double.Parse(Custo.Text);

        //calculo
        class2.Calculo1 = d * a * (v / 1000) * r;

        //chama Page1 passando objeto class2
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(class2));
    }
```

---

ou

---

```
private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if ((Densidade.Text == "") || (Volume.Text == "")
            || (Area.Text == "") || (Custo.Text == ""))
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            await DisplayAlert("Atenção", @"Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            class2 = new Class2();

            //Converte os valores obtidos na entrada em tipo double
            double a, d, r, v;
            a = Double.Parse(Area.Text);
            d = Double.Parse(Densidade.Text);
            r = Double.Parse(Custo.Text);
            v = Double.Parse(Volume.Text);

            //calculos
            class2.Calculo1 = d * a * (v / 1000) * r;

            //chama Page1 passando objeto class2
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(class2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ao invés de `a = Double.Parse(Area.Text);` tente usar `Double.TryParse(Area.Text, a);`

Comment: Tentei, aparece "Argumento 2 não deve ser transmitido com a palavra-chave 'out'". Não sei onde está o erro, nem como resolvê-lo.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de uma coisinha, o certo é `Double.TryParse(Area.Text, out var a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer insistir mesmo na mensagem que os campos precisam ser preenchidos então mude a verificação de vazio para:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Densidade.Text)
```

Obviamente fará para cada um deles. Pode usar o `||` mesmo.

E não faz uma conversão de dados sem ter certeza que ela é válida, para isto use assim:

```
if (!double.TryParse(Area.Text, out var a) DisplayAlert("Atenção", @"Valores digitados são inválidos", "Ok");
```

Pode usar um `||` aí também e ter só um `if` para os quatro dados a serem validados.

Mas é claro que pode omitir a verificação se está vazio e só controlar se o valor é válido, afinal se está vazio é inválido igual. Eu faria assim:

```
if (!double.TryParse(Area.Text, out var area) || !double.TryParse(Densidade.Text, out var densidade) || !double.TryParse(Custo.Text, out var custo) || !double.TryParse(Volume.Text, out var volume)) {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage()); //rever isto
        DisplayAlert("Atenção", @"Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos com valores válidos", "Ok");
    } else {
        var class2 = new Class2();
        class2.Calculo1 = densidade * area * (volume / 1000) * custo;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(class2)); //rever isto
    }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/XamarinExample.cs).

Aproveite e tire todos esses `await` e métodos `Async` que eles só estão deixando a aplicação mais lenta. Só volte usá-los em local onde precisa e depois que entender como ele funciona. Não está fazendo ficar mais rápido, pelo contrário, está mais lento assim. Tenho minhas dúvidas se a mensagem deveria ser apresentada assim, e se deveria ter esse `ok`, talvez seja outro "erro".

Alguma coisa me diz que esta `Classe2` não é necessária, fora o fato do nome não querer dizer nada. mesmo que a use, deveria ter um construtor melhor. O nome do campo dela também não faz sentido.

Se custo é um valor monetário deveria ser `decimal` e não `double`. É de se pensar se o resto também deveria.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sim, claro, tinha esquecido, obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar o `Double.TryParse(S, Result);`

```
 //Botão que transforma os dados em variáveis e passa para a página de resultados
    private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        class2 = new Class2();

        //Converte os valores obtidos na entrada em tipo double
        double a, d, r, v;
        Double.TryParse(Area.Text, out var a);
        Double.TryParse(Densidade.Text, out var d);
        Double.TryParse(Custo.Text, out var r);
        Double.TryParse(Volume.Text, out var v);

        //calculo
        class2.Calculo1 = d * a * (v / 1000) * r;

        //chama Page1 passando objeto class2
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(class2));
    }
```

Você pode usar ele como uma condição também, caso precise

```
if (Double.TryParse(Area.Text, out a))
  Console.WriteLine(number);
else
  Console.WriteLine("{0} Falha na conversão.", value);
```

> Quando esse método retorna, contém o equivalente do número de ponto
>   flutuante de precisão dupla do parâmetro S, se a conversão foi
>   bem-sucedida, ou zero, se a conversão falhou.

[Caso queira entender melhor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)